# How to forecast $Y/std(Y)$ using a linear model?

Tags: forecasting, linear-model, panel-data, heteroscedasticity, finance

How do I forecast $Y/std(Y)$ using a linear model?

I'm currently forecasting only $Y$, and the model is producing results where the larger predictions corresponding to higher variance $Y$. For example, if I take all the $Y$ where the prediction exceeds the 70th quantile, the variance of these observations is 30%, and if I take all the $Y$ where the prediction is lower than the 30th quantile, the variance of these observations is 10%. For my application, this is not desirable, I want the forecast not be able to separate the predictor by its variance.

This is a financial application where I wish to predict risk adjusted returns over the next 24 hours. I have 3 rows of data for AAPL (3 arbitrary days in the last 5 years), 5 rows of data for MSFT (5 arbitrary days in the last 5 years), etc. So it can be viewed as a panel data set that isn't balanced. The first column of data is $Y$, which is the return. The other columns are the design matrix $X$. It is a single data frame (hence the panel data designation). Ideally I can build a model:

$Y_{i,t}/std(Y_{i,t}) = \alpha + X_{i,t}\beta$

Note that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ shouldn't vary in either the time or cross-sectional dimensions.

Some of the predictors in $X$:

- yesterday's log price change
- some technical analysis signals
- some fundamental analysis signals

All predictors are $~N(0,1)$

Comment: If the data generating process is such that variance increases with the level of the series, why would you want your predictions *not* to reflect that? Also, what is $E(std(Y_i))$? Does $std$ by itself not involve the expectation?

Comment: @RichardHardy It's a financial application, the higher variance represents more risk. I wish to predict risk-adjusted returns.

Comment: GARCH models are often used for financial returns. They allow for time-varying variance. You can have the mean depend on variance, too, in a model known as GARCH-in-mean. This would reflect that higher risk commands higher return.

Comment: My application isn't time-series, each observation is iid with no heteroskedasticity

Comment: Then I do not quite understand what kind of data you have. You seem to indicate there is heteroskedasticity as some observations have variance of 30%, other 10%? Yet you say each observation is iid with no heteroskedasticity. Could you perhaps edit the post to explain your data and the variable behind it in more detail?

Comment: @RichardHardy I was wrong, it is heteroskedastic, just not in the time dimension so a GARCH model isn't appropriate. I'll add some more info to the OP.

Comment: *The first row... The other columns...* There is a mismatch there. Is that a balanced panel? Does not look like it if you have 3 observations for AAPL and 5 for MSFT. What variables are there, if I may?

Comment: @RichardHardy Corrected the typo, meant to say "column" not "row". It is not a balanced panel. I gave the long-winded example (3 rows of AAPL, 5 for MSFT) to illustrate that because I didn't know that terminology. I just added some examples of the predictors in the OP.

Comment: The distributions of the predictors usually do not matter much, but I find it curious that they are $N(0,1)$. Unless you have transformed them, subject-matter intuition tells they are not likely to be standard normal.

Comment: @RichardHardy

Yes I have transformed them. Some may have a kurtosis slightly higher than normal but nothing that would matter in a practical sense.

Comment: Why not simply employ a Generalized Linear Model that allows the variance to increase with an increasing mean?  This is one of the key features of these models?

Also, like @RichardHardy, I'm a bit confused about your data since you open the question saying you want to do forecasting.  Forecasting is a term used in time-series data.  But then you say you don't have time series data, but then mention you have panel data.